# Get x, y position of first and last drawn pixel in HTML canvas

Tags: java, html, image, canvas, position

[image]
I am drawing on canvas by mouse movement.

How can I get bounding  of my drawn in canvas?

Like fabricjs…

I am trying to get max X, min x, max y, min y

```
    object_crop=
{
x:DrawXY_Values.minX,
y:DrawXY_Values.minY,
width:DrawXY_Values.MaxX-DrawXY_Values.minX,
height:DrawXY_Values.MaxY-DrawXY_Values.minY,
}
```

… but problem appear when set `lineWidth >= 10`.

**The question is: How do I get the x/y coordinates of the upper left and lower right coordinates**

Comment: store the coordinates when the user starts drawing and do the same when he stops.

Comment: thank you jhamon but problem appear in image with bounding part of image cut out..

Comment: So what you want is not the first and last points coordinates but the upper left and lower right coordinates?

Comment: Store min and max of `x` and `y` during the whole drawing and check every pixel. And don't forget to inlcude the brush size into the calculation of the rectangle.

Comment: solved: thank you Tom , i am add brush size to ,, DrawXY_Values.minX-=brushImage.width
DrawXY_Values.minY-=brushImage.height